# Is it possible to sync my iTunes Up Next list with my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, ios, music

Currently, I don't have any of my music syncing between my computer and my iPhone, mostly because I have too much music to store it all on my phone. Is it possible to use the new Up Next list from iTunes 11 as a source for the music to by synced?

I've tried making a Smart Playlist and I've looked at a few other routes to getting this functionality, but to no avail. For anyone who is familiar with it, what I'd like to have is something like Rdio's "Sync to Mobile" feature, but with my own music library and using the "Up Next" feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Up Next list is something that is not portable in any way; it can't even be accessed by AppleScript, so you can't make a playlist even by using a script.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It's too bad that's not available, as I'd imagine it would be a neat thing to market, but I suppose it might be in later versions of iOS or iTunes.